# Python/Pandas Novice: unwanted changes to dataframe are carrying through when reassigning to a new variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame called df in which I am applying some simple transformations to (dropping columns, replacing values, etc.). The work I am performing requires me to have 2 copies of the data frame; one with the changes, and one in its original state. Here's an example of what I'm experiencing:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(x)
df=df2
#created a data frame called df2 that should reflect all changes in df at this point (i.e. I want the file to remain in its original state)

#changes are then made to df

print(df)
#some output

print(df2)
#all changes made to df are now showing in df2, which is what I don't want
```

It's clear I don't fully understand how data frames operate in Python, I am coming from an R background.
Is this normal behaviour, or is this something that shouldn't be happening? How can I go about making a copy of a dataframe at an earlier stage in its transformation without those changes carrying through to another variable containing the contents of df? As I type this I realize I may simply need to import the file once again with a different name. I hope this is clear, looking to understand what's happening here. Thanks for your help all.

Comment: The standard "assigning to a new variable" approach will return a shallow copy of the data frame. To get a deep copy, use [`df2 = df.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

Comment: Try `df2 = df.copy()`

Comment: Try `df2 = df.copy(deep=True)` then. `True` is the default value, but who knows what happened there. Explicitly setting it has to give you a deep copy

Comment: @LukasThaler that did it, very strange! Regardless thank you kindly

Comment: @LukasThaler **No** assignment doesn't copy *at all*

Comment: Not sure what to make of that @juanpa.arrivillaga I have used `df.copy()` for a while now and it always returned a copy of the DataFrame I called it on

Comment: I said *assignment*. You stated assigning to a new variable creates a shallow copy. That is incorrect. Assignment never copies, it merely creates a new reference to an object. And `.copy` should work.

Comment: Oh, I see. Learnt another thing today, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use [copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) function. Without using the copy function when you just assign `df` to `df2`, both `df` and `df2` will be pointing to the same object.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(x)
df2=df.copy()
```